# How do I find the package that provides a file?

Tags: package-management

Simple enough question: is there some shell command (or GUI method) I can use that, given the path to a file on my system, tells me what package put it there? Assuming the file did in fact come from a package, that is.

Bonus question: what if it's a file that isn't installed on my system? Is there, say, a website that will let me look up a file and see what packages, if any, provide it?

Comment: I've always wondered this myself - I know with YUM you can do yum whatprovides <filepath>/<filename> but I never really have found an alternative to that in Aptitude other than the Packages website

Comment: Same on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/10997/find-what-package-a-file-belongs-to-in-ubuntu-debian

Comment: None of the answers here actually cover the `Provides:` mechanism. In some more detail, a command like `mailx` or `sendmail` is not included as a binary in *any* package; instead, various packages install their own binaries and then make some of them available under a "canonical" name via `/etc/alternatives`. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/366135/how-to-search-for-packages-that-provides-a-virtual-package

Answer (score 711, accepted):

You can use `dpkg` command to find out which installed package owns a file:

From `man dpkg`:

```
-S, --search filename-search-pattern...
                  Search for a filename from installed packages.
```

Example:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

You can either search with a full path or with just the filename.

If you wish to search for files not yet installed on your computer, you can use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com), or `apt-file` as described in a [different answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file#1912).

Comment: I highly recommend using dlocate, which is updated daily for faster lookups.

Comment: Hint: if you do not know the full path, but just the command name, use `which` to find he program: `dpkg -S \`which firefox\``

Comment: This works for libraries as well, which is particularly handy if you have a binary that won't run because you can inspect it with ldd and use the full library paths to find the packages you are missing.

Comment: @DanielTChen, but `dlocate` may not do the job, if dlocate's database is out of date. You have to call `sudo update-dlocatedb` to update it.

Comment: If `dpkg` the exact path doesn't return anything (e.g. `dpkg /usr/bin/java`), try just the executable's name (e.g. `dpkg java`).

Comment: Also, note that the command may be a sym-link (like to /etc/alternatives), so use the final referenced file instead.

Comment: Like [in superuser](https://superuser.com/a/467513/500826) and [in unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394607/209677), this is the best alternative. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191983/209677) the alternative if package is not installed. If you get _dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern_ [try this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159001/how-to-find-the-package-that-installed-a-comand-if-dpkg-s-finds-no-path-beca/159002#159002) `dpkg -S "$(readlink -fn "$(which free)")"` (or a `dpkg -S command` but you'll other things).

Comment: Works but GNU/Linux man page documents `-S` at:  `man dpkg-query` (not at `man dpkg`)

Comment: You can also use `realpath` to resolve symlinks, like this: `dpkg -S $(realpath $(which <command>))`.

Comment: strangely, this doesn't work in 20.04 with ping: ```dpkg-query -S /usr/bin/ping
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/ping```

Comment: @hanshenrik that's because it's a symlink. `dpkg-query -S /bin/ping` works. Hence the discussion above about using `realpath`.

Answer (score 419):

The [`apt-file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/apt-file.1.html) command can do this for you from the command line. I use it frequently when building packages from source. For files provided by packages that are already installed on your system, [`apt-cache`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man8/apt-cache.8.html) is another choice.

To install `apt-file`, do:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then, you need to update it's database:

```
sudo apt-file update
```

And, finally, search the file:

```
$ apt-file find kwallet.h
kdelibs5-dev: /usr/include/kwallet.h
libkf5wallet-dev: /usr/include/KF5/KWallet/kwallet.h
```

However a much friendlier way is to use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) website. They have an option to "search the contents of packages" for a specific filename.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer. But in response to *Ubuntu Packages Search*, I might argue that a shell program this simple is extremely friendly and easy to remember (once you know it). If you use dpkg, apt-get, or aptitude as your standard tools, there is nothing friendly about firing up Chrome to surf the internet!

Comment: @user2097818 The reason this isn't the accepted answer is that my primary question is restricted to files on the system and packages which are installed. `apt-file` often finds false positives, i.e. packages that aren't installed. Of course this answer is great for the "bonus question".

Comment: For those from the Redhat side of the world - `apt-file search <>` is the closest analog to `dnf/yum whatprovides <>`.

Comment: I aliased `apt-file find` as `apt-find` long time ago and it's really handy! Btw, latest versions require root for `apt-file update`.

Comment: I guess the question is why in the world is this functionality not built into `apt`, `apt-get`, or one of the other default `apt-*` programs. It seems like key piece of any package manager's search capabilities.

Comment: After running the `sudo apt install apt-file` on Ubuntu 18, I get `Package apt-file is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

Comment: A couple of caveats: 1) you have to install apt-file which is really annoying; 2) it is much slower than dpkg -S, eg on my system the latter takes less than half a second, whereas apt-file find takes 20 seconds! 3) most often, if you have a path on your system, then the package is installed, so why pay for the overhead of apt-file?

Comment: @theferrit32 Precisely my question. I'm used to `pacman` and it always provided that feature

Answer (score 55):

There's also apt-file for looking up files in packages that aren't installed. For example:

```
apt-file list packagename
```

Answer (score 24):

You can search the contents of packages included in the various Ubuntu releases on the [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) website. Look under the heading "[Search the contents of packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents)".

For example, here are the search results for libnss3.so in focal (20.04):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libnss3.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=focal&arch=any

Comment: This recently just returns an error.

Answer (score 20):

You mean, which package and not which application. The application is your package manager, e.g. `Software Center`.

Using `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
dpkg -S tracker-extract
dpkg -S tracker-miner-fs
```

*Example*

```
% dpkg -S /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
tracker: /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
```

---

Using `apt-file`:

```
apt-file search /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
```

or also possible:

```
apt-file search --regex /tracker-extract$
apt-file search --regex /tracker-miner-fs$
```

*Example*

```
% apt-file search /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
tracker: /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
```

---

Or online [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), in the section `Search the contents of packages`.

[image]

*Example*

[image]

Comment: You mean, which package and not which application. The application is your package manager, e.g. Software Center.  Okay.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

None of these suggestions helped me find which package installed this/these applications though.  All searches just lead back to "Tracker".

I suspected it was Enthoughts' Canopy though.  That mile long EULA reminded me of my old Microsoft Windows daze, with which, I am so glad I am no longer involved.

I saw that Tracker was installed yesterday so, as root, I got rid of it, along
with Enthoughts' Canopy and, all problems are solved.

I really thank you for all your help.  It is such a great thing to have such
support.

Thanks again!

Kevin

Answer (score 7):

This is an extension to [Alexx Roche's excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1016770/146273). I tried to make an edit to that answer, but [it got rejected](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/858362) (though not by Alexx)

---

I was trying to track down what installed `which` on my system. After a little work I created `/usr/local/bin/apt-whatprovides`

```
#!/bin/sh
#apt-whatprovides ver. 201801010101 Copyright alexx, MIT Licence
#rdfa:deps="[realpath,apt-file,grep,which,sh,echo]"

BINARY="$(realpath $(which $@) 2>/dev/null)"
[ -z "$BINARY" ] && BINARY="$@"
echo Searching for $BINARY
PACKAGE="$(apt-file search $BINARY|grep -E ":.*[^-.a-zA-Z0-9]${BINARY}$")"
echo "${PACKAGE}"
```

Though for most THINGs that are installed you can just use:

```
apt-file search $(realpath $(which THING)) | grep 'THING$'
```

For THINGs that are not installed, you can use:

```
apt-file search THING | grep '/THING$'
```

The `apt-whatprovides` script works for files that are and are not on your system. For example, my system lacked `dig` but had `ping` so this it what resulted:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-whatprovides ping
Searching for /bin/ping
inetutils-ping: /bin/ping
iputils-ping: /bin/ping

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-whatprovides dig
Searching for dig
dnsutils: /usr/bin/dig
epic4: /usr/share/epic4/script/dig
epic4-help: /usr/share/epic4/help/8_Scripts/dig
knot-dnsutils: /usr/bin/dig
```

Notice that `Searching for` is a complete path for `ping` (installed) and just the binary name for `dig` not installed. This helped me discover that I needed to install `dnsutils` without needing to go search https://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents

Comment: This is such a good answer that I should delete mine!

Comment: with `apt-file -x ...` you don't need to `grep` the output, hence you get slightly shorter and more convenient one liner like `apt-file -ix search "$( realpath $( which THING ) )$"` (installed packages) resp. `apt-file -ix search '/THING$'` (not installed packages).

Comment: well, not even that my one liner are more convenient... i found one corner case in which they actually show a more useful resp. any result at all: if the binary is linked and uses a different name, the `grep` edition shows nothing while the `apt-file -x` edition still filters for the correct command/path. **||** anyway, for installed packages `dpkg -S $( which THING )` or `apt contains $( which THING )` is IMHO still the better choice.

Comment: `lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*Contents* | grep -F "${BINARY#/}"$'\t' | sort -u` is considerably faster than `apt-file search ... | grep` and way faster than `apt-file search -x`.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to track down what installed `which` on my system. After a little work I created apt-whatprovides

```
#!/bin/sh
#apt-whatprovides ver. 201801010101 Copyright alexx, MIT Licence
#rdfa:deps="[realpath,apt-file,grep,which,sh,echo]"

BINARY=$(realpath $(which $@))
PACKAGE=$(apt-file search $BINARY|grep -E ":\s*${BINARY}$")
echo ${PACKAGE%:*}
```

Though for most THINGs you can just use

```
apt-file search $(realpath $(which THING))|grep 'THING$'
```

Comment: Alexx, I love this answer. I hope you don't mind my edit. I made it also work for files that are not installed on the system. I made a backup at https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/41e91e858fdf070720704179aa08ed62 and will create my own answer if you revert/reject it.

Comment: Update: It feels slimy to copy pasta this answer and make subtle changes to it, but my edit got rejected. I hope you feel like I maintained the integrity of your answer [in mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057124/146273).

Comment: Feel free to edit or hack; anything that makes it better for you, (that's why I added MIT Licence! I don't even need credit.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
$ apt-file --fixed-string  search /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

or,

```
$ apt-file --fixed-string --package-only search /bin/ls
coreutils
```

You can also read from file like bellow:

```
echo "/bin/ls" | apt-file --fixed-string --from-file --package-only search -
```

Instead you `echo` you can use like `cat files.txt`.

For **Linux Mint** you can use `apt` to do it.

```
$ apt contains /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

The output is same as:

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

**P.S.** In the above commands, you can replace `--fixed-string` with `-F`; `--package-only` with `-l` and `--from-file` with `-f`.

Comment: `apt contains` is not a valid operation, at least for `apt` v2.4.8.

Comment: @TeemuLeisti apparently it's from linux mint. https://www.maketecheasier.com/ultimate-guide-apt-and-apt-get-commands/

Comment: @qwr i have checked the answer after you mentioned that this is linux mint only. Yes you are right. It is not even in debian 12, apt 2.6.1. I have updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

One reason you might have to do this is if you are compiling software which there already is an ubuntu package, you can run `apt-get build-dep $PACKAGENAME`. That will install all packages you need to compile `$PACKAGENAME`.

Answer (score 1):

**Why**:

Different distro has its own way, too many commands to remember  o(╥﹏╥)o

**How**:

A universal solution: `pacapt -Qo file_path`

**Outcome**:

On ubuntu:

```
$ pacapt -Qo /usr/bin/iostat
sysstat: /usr/bin/iostat
```

On centos:

```
$ pacapt -Qo /usr/bin/iostat
sysstat-10.1.5-19.el7.x86_64
```

Even can find path itself:

```
$ pacapt -Qo iostat
sysstat: /usr/share/man/man1/iostat.1.gz
sysstat: /usr/bin/cifsiostat
sysstat: /usr/bin/iostat
sysstat: /usr/share/man/man1/cifsiostat.1.gz
```

**What** is [pacapt](https://github.com/icy/pacapt):

> pacapt is a wrapper for many package managers

**Install**:

**Simply download the portable script**:

`wget -O $HOME/bin/pacapt https://github.com/icy/pacapt/raw/ng/pacapt`

Comment: What's "`pacapt`"? How does one get that?

Comment: @pomsky I have updated pacapt information. And you can get pacapt by wget as descripted in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `dpkg -S` but it only works when it's pointing at the canonical file.

DPKG can't find the file I'm looking for:

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70
```

Some path of the path is a symbolic link. If you don't want to inspect each parts one by one, use `realpath`

```
$ realpath /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70.1
```

DPKG works with the real path (canonical) of the file:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70.1
libicu70:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70.1
```

Or, all at once:

```
$ dpkg -S $(realpath /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70)
libicu70:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70.1
```