# If I need a specific library how do I find out which packages can install that library?

Tags: package-management, libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

If I know the name of a library (Eg. libnss3.so) how do I figure out which package to install to get this library? Is there an easier way to do this?