# apt-get or aptitude equivalent to yum whatprovides

Tags: apt, aptitude

Is there an equivalent to the yum "whatprovides" option in apt-get?

For example on CentOS

```
yum whatprovides /usr/share/gdm/themes/TreeFlower/background.png
```

Tells me

```
redhat-logos-4.9.99-11.el5.centos.noarch : CentOS-related icons and pictures.
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/gdm/themes/TreeFlower/background.png
```

Can I get similar functionality on the command line in Ubuntu?

Comment: In nower days it is `yum provides` in Fedora. There is a very nice summary for the differences of package management tools from Fedora/Red Hat to Ubuntu/Debian: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/ RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This depends on whether the package containing the file is already installed. If so, use `dpkg -S filename`.

If your intention is to find out which package to install to get a certain file, one option is to use the online [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/): scroll down to "Search the contents of packages". Make sure that the right distribution is selected. If you're looking for a files irrespective of the path, check the appropriate option.

There is also [`apt-file`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AptFile). Because this method required updating the files database, however, I prefer the other, instant option.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com really is a gem that doesn't seem to get mentioned often enough.  It's inherited of course from http://packages.debian.org

Answer (score 31):

You want the 'apt-file' command.

```
apt-file search /usr/share/gdm/themes/TreeFlower/background.png
```

Before using it, you may need to create or update its database by running:

```
apt-file update
```

Answer (score 1):

`wajig whichpkg /usr/share/gdm/themes/TreeFlower/background.png`

You'll have to install wajig, which is a frontend to a bunch of utilities related to apt. If you use wajig, you can use all of those tools without having to memorize their names.

Comment: whatprovides wajig though?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this the same question as this [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

I prefer the `dpkg -S <filepath>` command

Comment: `dpkg -S <filepath>` only works if the package is already installed. I think the OP was asking how to find which package they might want to install that would provide that.

Comment: dnf also works with wildcards. Command `dnf whatprovides */background.png` will find all packages with file named `background.png` in any directory.