# Ubuntu - any good method to know which package contains the specified app?

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

My mount utility doesn't support ext4, so I plan to update it.
How to determine which package contain an app, such as mount?

sudo apt-get install

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file search <filename>
```

What version of ubuntu are you using? If the kernel supports ext4, mount should!

Make sure you're using the correct syntax

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdax /dir
```

if its a currently installed package (which mount is), you can also do

```
dpkg -S /bin/mount
```

Comment: Thanks, but it fails: $ sudo apt-file search mount
sudo: apt-file: command not found
$ sudo cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.24-24-generic (buildd@palmer) (gcc version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)) #1 SMP Tue Jul 7 19:46:39 UTC 2009

Comment: It seems no apt-file command.

Comment: you need to install apt-file first, sudo apt-get install apt-file

Comment: however in your case, dpkg -S should work

Comment: My kernel doesn't support ext4. I have checked /proc/filesystem

Comment: There's a command called 'apt-cache'. 'apt-cache search' searches for packages. 'apt-cache show' displays information about a particular package (including whether or not it is installed). apt-cache is available by default iirc

Answer (score 0):

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/
```

Enter "ext4" and click on Description and search.  You will soon see that you should have e2fsprogs installed to have full ext4 support (mostly fsck).  The kernel controls whether you can mount, though.

Answer (score 0):

First, direct answer to your question:

**dpkg -S**  
will return a list of all packages which have files matching that string.
You probably want to pass the full path (which you can using which)

**which mount** -> /bin/mount
**dpkg -S /bin/mount** -> mount

Also,
**apt-cache search ext4** will return all of the packages which use ext4.
I'd expect you're more likely to need to update e2fsprogs than mount