# Find what package supplied a tool / application in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, apt, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

When you type a command in the terminal in Ubuntu that you have not installed but can supplied by a package Ubuntu will suggest the package to be installed.

How do I do the other way around? How do I look for what package supplied the command I am typing in a terminal?

> dpkg -S /usr/bin/termit

returns

```
termit: /usr/bin/termit
```

> apt-file find /usr/bin/termit

returns

```
termit: /usr/bin/termit
```

Where `termit` is an terminal emulator supplied by package `termit`.

[image]

Comment: Supplied solutions do not work in 11.10.

Comment: Uh? I don't have 11.10 to check, but I'd be very surprised if `dpkg -S` didn't work, it's a basic command that doesn't change over time, and you even seem to be saying in your edited question that it does work. `apt-file find` should work too, though you might need to run `sudo apt-file update` once and for all first (previous versions of Ubuntu did it automatically when you installed the `apt-file` package). In what way are `dpkg -S` and `apt-file find` (which were given as answers here as well as in the earlier similar question) unsuitable?

Comment: Then either I am doing it wrong or there is something wrong, anyways a solution would be nice. Included a screen shot, let me know if something is wrong. Thanks for the comment anyways. `apt-file find` was run after update.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question then? As far as I can tell, the screenshot shows you getting the answer you wanted, which is that the file `/usr/bin/termit` is provided by the package `termit`.

Comment: Holy sh*t big fail, really. It works as it should. Just sleepy I think. Thanks for forcing it down :)

Comment: Gave reputation to answers, will close this in 3 mins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `apt-file` installed and configured, you can do:

```
apt-file find <filename>
```

This is also handy when you're looking for a command that you don't have installed yet, e.g. if you're working from instructions seen on the web that use a command you don't have.

If you only want to query packages that are installed, you can use:

```
dpkg -S <pattern>
```

E.g. for a file that is installed:

```
% apt-file find /usr/bin/oodraw
openoffice.org-draw: /usr/bin/oodraw
% dpkg -S oodraw
openoffice.org-draw: /usr/share/man/man1/oodraw.1.gz
openoffice.org-draw: /usr/bin/oodraw
```

and for a file that is not installed:

```
% dpkg -S /usr/bin/python3.1
dpkg: /usr/bin/python3.1 not found.
% apt-file find /usr/bin/python3.1
python3.1-dbg: /usr/bin/python3.1-dbg
python3.1-dbg: /usr/bin/python3.1-dbg-config
python3.1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python3.1
python3.1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python3.1-dbg-gdb.py
python3.1-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/bin/python3.1-gdb.py
python3.1-dev: /usr/bin/python3.1-config
python3.1-minimal: /usr/bin/python3.1
```

Comment: This is not giving me what I am looking for. ie: `apt-file find termit` returns everything expect the name of the package that installed `termit`. `apt-file find /usr/bin/termit' only returns the path to the file.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about apt-file.

Comment: Note that for apt-file to be useful, you have to run apt-file update first -- it takes a while to build the database the first time, but after that finding what you want is quick. (Usually quicker than `dpkg -S`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using /usr/bin/ls (you can find absolute paths of executables via the `which` command), you can find what package provided by running:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls
```

Alternatively, running

```
dpkg -S ls
```

will search for files named `ls` (or some heuristic like that) in all installed packages and return a list of them for you, formatted as `PACKAGE: /path/to/file`.

Comment: This is not what I want, I know they are installed, I know where they are, I want to know where they are coming from.