# Package ubuntu-release-upgrader does not exist

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

I got this error when I tried to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 from the Update Manager.

> Package ubuntu-release-upgrader does not exist

Is there anything can be done to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried updating Ubuntu using the terminal ?

Comment: currently trying  sudo do-release-upgrade

Comment: Ok, If anything happens tell us :)

Comment: @Suhaib tried it and it estimate the download will took 52 days. I still download it. On the other hand, I download the iso file and it will finish in an hour. Can the upgrade done from usb stick or live cd?

Comment: Yea you can do that. insert the liveCD/Usb and run the installation. Then a window will show up dng the installation procedure that will ask you if you want to upgrade your Ubuntu instead of installing a new one

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to install the package by that name. Whether or not you are, the problem will likely be solved if you install **`ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`** instead:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
```

That's the package that gives you what you need to upgrade using the `do-release-upgrade` utility. There is no installable package called just `ubuntu-release-upgrader`.

This applies upgrades involving currently supported upgrades as well, such as 12.04 to 14.04 and 14.04 to 16.04.

To be specific, [`ubuntu-release-upgrader` is a source package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader). Source packages can build one or more binary packages, and sometimes one of them has the same name as the source package, but not always. As that Launchpad page shows, the binary packages it provides are currently `python3-distupgrade`, `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`, `ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk`, `ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt`. See also [the binary package database](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ubuntu-release-upgrader&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Note that the `do-release-upgrade` executable is [provided by `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=do-release-upgrade&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any).

*I'm not sure if this would have helped, as you wouldn't necessarily have known the package that provides `do-release-upgrade` was hte one you needed... but for general information about finding what package you need to use a command, see [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)*

---

It can be useful to install available updates to your system before attempting to upgrade it to a new release:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudp apt-get upgrade
```

*One* of the benefits of this is that if something goes wrong, it may be easier for you to figure out than during the release upgrade.

If after installing `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` and updating most of the packages on your system as shown above (which will automatically include that one) you still have problems--or if you would have to upgrade through multiple releases to get where you want to go--then you should consider following [Suhaib's advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203566/package-ubuntu-release-upgrader-does-not-exist#comment253854_203566) to attempt upgrading from the installer, or perhaps even offloading all your documents and important files, wiping the disk, and starting from scratch.