# Installing missing package that provides Xm/Xm.h

Tags: compiling, gcc, mesa

I'm compiling a software package that requires a header file.  The header file is missing from my Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit) installation.  During the compilation using `make`, `gcc` and `gfortran`, I receive the following error message.

```
XMstr.c:7:19: fatal error: Xm/Xm.h: No such file or directory
```

Googling for an answer leads me to believe that a MESA library needs to be installed on my system, but I can't find an exact match for the package name.

What might be the name of the package that I need to install?  Does the package have the same name on more recent Ubuntu distros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need either **openmotif** or **lesstif** header files which you can get this way:

```
# lesstif:
sudo apt-get install lesstif2-dev

# openmotif is not available in ubuntu repos
# but you can get it from it's official site:
# http://www.opengroup.org/openmotif/
# but it wants registaration before downloading.
```

Comment: Thank you; installing lesstif2-dev does indeed get rid of the error and the compile proceeds.

Answer (score 8):

The package to resolve your specific issue can be found in the other answer. In case you run into other similar issues later, try this more general approach:

1. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/
2. Scroll down to "Search the contents of packages"
3. Enter the filename you're looking for in the text box.
4. Select "packages that contain files whose names end with the keyword"
5. Select the right distribution version and architecture
6. Hit [search].

For [`Xm/Xm.h`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=Xm%2FXm.h&mode=&suite=oneiric&arch=any) it looks like this:

```
File                                                    Packages
/usr/include/Xm/Xm.h                                    lesstif2-dev, libmotif-dev
/usr/lib/TenDRA/lib/include/motif/1_2.api/Xm/Xm.h       tendra [not amd64]
```

An alternative command-line approach of finding the package for a file is using `apt-file` as can be seen in the question [How to get a list of files for a package I haven't installed yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225746/how-to-get-a-list-of-files-for-a-package-i-havent-installed-yet)

Comment: Thank you; I didn't know that packages.ubuntu.com has this functionality. +1 for adding this, and for enlightening this topic further. I am bound to be using this when I run into further issues.

Comment: You can also do the above locally with `apt-file search Xm.h`. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

Comment: @GerhardBurger I know, I've provided [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/225751/88802) with that myself some time earlier in a more targeted question. See my updated answer. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu 18.04.3, I was able to get the correct missing library Xm.h using

```
sudo apt-get install libmotif-dev
```