# How to get a list of files for a package I haven't installed yet?

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg, apt-cache

`apt-cache search` returns list of available packages. In my case I would like to look at  the list of files that would be installed on my PC in case I install the package `usb-creator-gtk`.

Something like `dpkg-query -L` does for an already installed package.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got at least these two options.

First one, use `apt-file` for packages you haven't installed yet.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file list usb-creator-gtk
usb-creator-gtk: /usr/bin/usb-creator-gtk
usb-creator-gtk: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usbcreator/frontends/gtk/__init__.py
usb-creator-gtk: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usbcreator/frontends/gtk/frontend.py
[...]
```

Second one, use the [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) website to locate the package, then all the way down on the page in the "Download" section, you'll find a link `[list of files]`. Example for your package in Bionic (18.04) is [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/usb-creator-gtk/filelist).

Either way, please remember that packages might install more files in their install scripts!