# Running ePsxe 1.9 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, emulation

So I wanted to give ePsxe 1.9 a go on Ubuntu (of course, I legally own both the console and games I am planning on running).  I started out by downloading [ePSXe v1.9.0 for Linux](http://www.epsxe.com/download.php) from the official web site.  I then extracted the binary and attempted to run it.  This is what happened:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is going on here?  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you need to find the package that contains the file `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`.  If you take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/47437) and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file # Installs apt-file
sudo apt-file update # Tells apt-file to update its cache
apt-file search libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 # Has apt-file find the package with your file
```

Then you can see that the package `libgtk2.0-0` contains that particular library.  With that, all you should need to do is install `libgtk2.0-0`:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

And you should be set!

Answer (score 18):

Ok this are the libraries I had to install to make this emulator run

because I am using an x64 system and epsxe is x32 i had to install 32 bit libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2:i386

sudo apt-get install libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Comment: i was looking for this answer! This should be highlighted..