# Problem running ePSXe on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, emulation

I cannot get epsxe to run on my 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have tried [Running ePsxe 1.9 on Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370079/running-epsxe-1-9-on-ubuntu-13-10) but it still does not work. I have downloaded BIOS from http://www.emuparadise.me/biosfiles/bios.html (PSX BIOS Pack (15 Images) - PSX - SCPH1001.BIN). Every time I click Run BIOS, the program crashes.

I run the program by clicking the program directly (like in Win by double-clicking .exe). Should I run it from the Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with ePSXe & this is how I fixed it.
(I've used BIOS files you provided)

1) Navigate to your ePSXe/bios
2) Rename **PSX - SCPH1001.BIN** to **scph1001.bin** (extension must be in lowercase)
3) Run ePSXe from terminal