# How can I uninstall Adobe acroread when nothing else works?

Tags: apt, uninstall, dpkg, adobe-reader, software-uninstall

I have checked all similar questions. None of them offer a working solution in my case. This is not a duplicate. Here are the details of my *unique* situation:

```
$ acroread
```

This causes Adobe Acrobat Reader 9 to open and run.

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

I am running **Kubuntu**

```
$ which acroread
/usr/bin/acroread

$ ls -la /usr/bin/acroread
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 15  2013 /usr/bin/acroread -> /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread

/opt/Adobe/Reader9$ find . -iname UNINSTALL
/opt/Adobe/Reader9$

$ sudo apt-get remove acroread
Package acroread is not installed, so not removed

$ dpkg -s acroread
Package: acroread
Status: deinstall ok config-files
Priority: extra
Section: partner/text
Installed-Size: 65
Maintainer: Brian Thomason <brian.thomason@canonical.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 9.5.5-1precise1
Config-Version: 9.5.5-1precise1
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, acroread-bin, nspluginwrapper
Description: Adobe Reader
 Adobe Reader allows you to view navigate and print PDF files. This version
 adds advanced forms support (save), better integration with Adobe Acrobat
 workflows, customizable toolbars and better overall performance.
 .
 This package provides the English version of Adobe Reader 9.

sudo dpkg --purge acroread
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching acroread

sudo dpkg -r acroread
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching acroread

$ sudo locate adobereader
(no results returned)

$ sudo locate acroread
/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh
/home/me/.kde/share/icons/NITRUX-KDE/apps/scalable/acroread.svg
/var_cache_apt_archives/acroread_9.2-1jaunty1_amd64.deb
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Shell/acroread.1.gz
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Resource/Shell/acroread_tab
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread
/usr/bin/acroread
/usr/share/applications/acroread.desktop
/usr/share/doc/acroread-bin
/usr/share/doc/acroread-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/acroread-bin/copyright
/usr/share/icons/mono/scalable/apps/acroread.svgz
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/128x128/apps/acroread.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/16x16/apps/acroread.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/apps/acroread.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/32x32/apps/acroread.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/48x48/apps/acroread.png
/usr/share/icons/oxygen/64x64/apps/acroread.png
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/acroread-bin
/usr/share/man/man1/acroread.1.gz
/usr/share/scribus/icons/acroread16.png
/usr/share/scribus/icons/acroread22.png
/usr/share/scribus/icons/acroread32.png
/var/cache/apt/archives/acroread-bin_9.5.5-1precise1_i386.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/acroread_9.5.5-1precise1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread-bin.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread-bin.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread.postrm

$ sudo apt-get remove --purge acroread*
```

after running this last command, acroread is still installed and typing `acroread` at any prompt still causes it to open and run.

Comment: The `apt-get` and `dpkg` commands are doing nothing because in their records (well, `apt-get` uses `dpkg`), `acroread` isn't installed. How did you first install acroread?

Comment: @saiarcot895 - "How did you first install acroread?" I don't remember. But the location (/opt/) makes me think I downloaded a .DEB file from Adobe. But that's just a guess.

Comment: The presence of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread.list` suggests it was installed from a `.deb` file, but then `sudo dpkg -r acroread` should have seen it. I'm not sure how, but perhaps it was named something slightly different? You can try `dpkg -l '*acroread*'` to use wildcards, or `dpkg -S /usr/bin/acroread` to see [what package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file) provides the binary.

Comment: Install tree using `sudo apt-get install tree` and then provide the output of `tree /opt/Adobe/Reader9/`

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get remove adobereader-enu --purge
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This answer would benefit substantially, if you were to edit it to add some explanation (or at least to tell the user exactly *what to do* with that line).