# How to get appropriate lib package name for a specific header file

Tags: compiling, dependencies, libraries

It's common problem that we get some error like `"abc.h no such file"` when compile source. Only way to find the solution(as i know) is search in internet. What i need to do, compile the source, it will give me some errors and then i have to install the dev by searching in internet.

Is there any way that i can get lib package name by the header file name? Assume i need `crypto.h` file, `libssl-dev` contains this file.

But how could i know? Where should i search for it? Is there any reference site or program?

Comment: Really !! That was about package. And my one is to find the dev package name which contains a specific header file.

Comment: @unknown can you please explain why gave you close vote??

Comment: A header file is just a file and a dev package is just a package. Search for the package that contains `abc.h`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This resembles the question [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Since you are looking for packages you don't have in your system, I recommend using `apt-file search <header file>`. You can fine-tune your search to avoid expansion (that is, do not list *foocrypto.html* if you are looking for *crypto.h*).

Your command would look like `apt-file -x search '/crypto.h$'`

```
user@host$ apt-file -x search '/crypto.h$'

aroarfw-dev: /usr/include/aroarfw/crypto.h
asterisk-dev: /usr/include/asterisk/crypto.h
crtmpserver-dev: /usr/include/crtmpserver/common/utils/misc/crypto.h
libfaifa-dev: /usr/include/faifa/crypto.h
libgnutls-dev: /usr/include/gnutls/crypto.h
libntfs-dev: /usr/include/ntfs/crypto.h
libroar-dev: /usr/include/libroar/crypto.h
libsrtp0-dev: /usr/include/srtp/crypto.h
libssl-dev: /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h
libsyslog-ng-dev: /usr/include/syslog-ng/crypto.h
libxmlsec1-dev: /usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/crypto.h
libxmlsec1-dev: /usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/gcrypt/crypto.h
libxmlsec1-dev: /usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/gnutls/crypto.h
libxmlsec1-dev: /usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/nss/crypto.h
libxmlsec1-dev: /usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/openssl/crypto.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64/include/config/crypto.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64/include/config/rt2x00/lib/crypto.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/crypto.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common-rt: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common-rt/include/linux/crypto.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64/include/config/crypto.h
linux-headers-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64/include/config/rt2x00/lib/crypto.h
```

Moreover, if you know beforehand that the package is named *something-dev* or *libsomething-dev* you can pipe it to `grep`.

`apt-file -x search '/crypto.h$' | grep '^lib[^:]*-dev'`

This returns only packages named *lib*-dev*.

Finally, if you only want the *name* of the packages (and not the path to the file) so you get a nice list of packages (one per line), you can use `grep -o` instead.

`apt-file -x search '/crypto.h$' | grep -o '^lib[^:]*-dev'`

Happy coding :)