# apt-file equivalent to search for source files

Tags: package-management, apt-file

I find the apt-file utility very comfortable to find the package that delivers a given file. If I wanted to find the package that delivered `/bin/bash` I would simply type

```
apt-file find /bin/bash
```

and get a list of packages that contain that file.

Now I wonder can I somehow search for source files of packages?
For example if I wanted to find all packages whose source structure contains `lib/glob/glob.h`? (It is bash in this case).

Comment: I doubt this exists very strongly, since the packaging system doesn't add information about files within the source packages. For example, you can get a list of files for the binary package [unity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity), but not for the source package [unity](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/unity).

Comment: Are you willing to download all the sources with `apt-get source` 1st?

Comment: Rinzwind: no of course I do not want to get all the packages. I thought maybe there is an index like there is for apt-file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)