# Cannot install WGET in Ubuntu 12.04.5 lts

Tags: 12.04, apt, wget

What do you think are the reasons that causes this error?

```
The program 'wget' is currently not installed.  
You can install it by typing:sudo apt-get install wget
```

If I type `sudo apt-get install wget` the output is this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
wget is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

I checked if wget is installed by `wget --version` but nothing comes up. 
I cannot install `wget`. I have internet connection. I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS server**. This is newly installed. I'm trying to install `asterisk` on this one but cannot get started. Any information will be a great help.

Comment: whats the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep "wget"`

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are root when running apt-get. Then if you are:
Try:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get remove wget` then install wget
- try `sudo apt-get upgrade` then try all these things again.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out what files were installed by using

```
dpkg -L wget
```

On my system (YMMV) it shows me that `/usr/bin/wget` is one of the installed files.

I suspect that your `$PATH` is set incorrectly. Please show us the result of

```
echo $PATH  
/bin/ls -l /usr/bin/wget
```

and check your `~/.bashrc` for how `PATH` is set up.

Answer (score 1):

#### `sudo apt-get install --reinstall wget` will replace any deleted files.

When the `bash` shell's default command-not-found handler in Ubuntu--which is what displayed the message you saw when you tried to run `wget`--tells you that a program isn't installed, but the package that it says provides it *is* installed, **this usually means that the file was deleted**. In that case, you can *re*install the package, and the file will be replaced.

Just running the command that it tells you to run won't do that, because if reinstallation of already-installed packages were perfomed by default when you use `apt install` or  `apt-get install`, then users would constantly be reintalling things they didn't mean to reinstall.

To reinstall a package, **pass the `--reinstall` flag** as well. In your case, for the `wget` package:

```
sudo apt-get --install reinstall wget
```

The `apt` command also accepts this syntax, i.e., you can replace `apt-get` with `apt` in that command, in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and later, though that command still works fine. (It's fine to use `apt-get`, even on systems that have the `apt` command, too.)

The alternative of removing and then reinstalling `wget` in two separate steps is inadvisable, because if you remove `wget` with the `remove` or `purge` action, then any packages that *depend* on it will also be removed. Those packages are *not* automatically reinstalled when you subsequently install `wget` (though if you explicitly install *them*, then the `wget` package gets installed if it wasn't already, assuming the package manager *knows* it was missing).

For information about how to investigate such problems, and other possible causes, see below. What follows is secondary and not needed in most cases.

---

#### If you *want* to check first...

As described above, a missing file is the most common cause of the problem, but there are other causes that reinstalling the package can *also* solve--see below--so I suggest simply proceeding to do so. However, if you feel like *checking* if the file has been deleted, then you can run:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/wget
```

In general, if you don't know what file *should* be providing the command, you can run `dpkg -S wget` to see a list of files provided directly by *any* package that have `wget` in their names, or (as [waltinator suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/582228/22949)) `dkpg -L wget` to list all files that the `wget` package directly provides. However, I suggest instead using https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to look it up, since the interface is easy to use and it will give you the right answer even if your system's package manager turns out to be broken or misconfigured.

See also [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

#### This is *not* likely to be caused by a `PATH` problem.

There are other possible causes, but in my experience they are much less common. In particular, if your `PATH` is set incorrectly, that will usually *not* cause the command-not-found handler to suggest installing a package:

```
ek@Kip:~$ nonexistent-command
nonexistent-command: command not found
ek@Kip:~$ curl
The program 'curl' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install curl
ek@Kip:~$ wget
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
ek@Kip:~$ PATH=
ek@Kip:~$ nonexistent-command
bash: nonexistent-command: No such file or directory
ek@Kip:~$ curl
bash: curl: No such file or directory
ek@Kip:~$ wget
bash: wget: No such file or directory
```

#### Another possible cause is a deleted symlink used by the alternatives system.

A more plausible cause for this *kind* of problem--besides the file being deleted as described above--would be if [the alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) maintained the command as a [symbolic link](http://foldoc.org/symlink) to an executable, and the symbolic link itself had been deleted, while the actual executable remained.

In that situation, you wouldn't have to reinstall the package--but reinstalling still typically *would* fix it, because it would usually set up the newly installed command as the default by remaking the symbolic link and having it point to the executable that was installed.

Furthermore, **`wget` in Ubuntu is not managed by the alternatives system** because there is only one implementation of `wget` in Ubuntu's repositories. So this is not the cause of the situation described specifically in the question here, though it is occasionally the cause of problems that manifest similarly.

Comment: Is there a method by which I could determine that the file has been deleted, and somehow `apt` thinks that the package has been installed?

Comment: @CharlesGreen Yes, you can just use `ls` to check if the file is still there. If you're not sure what file it should be, you can look that up. I've just expanded my answer with more information, including details about that. However, you very well may not want to bother checking this, since there are other problems that reinstalling the package can also fix (I've added information about that, too).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem with your $PATH. Have a look at [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) for more info.

Please open a terminal, enter the following commands one at a time, and let us know what the results are:

```
    $ echo $PATH
    $ cat ~/.pam_environment
```