# Write greek in latex for ubuntu

Tags: latex

I'm totally new in ubuntu. I want to write mathematical papers in greek in latex.

From the synaptic package manager I downloaded texlive and texstudio.
Everything works fine in english, but i can't write in greek.

I wrote the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ααα
\end{document}
\enddocumentclass{article}
```

And texstudio returned

```
''file babel.sty , unknown option greek...''
```

I tried that

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ααα
\end{document}
\enddocumentclass{article}
```

And it returned

```
''inputenc.sty :file iso-8859-7.def not found ''
```

Please tell me what to do to fix this problem.

If it's easy, give me some straight instructions if I have to use the terminal.

Comment: Did you install [`texlive-lang-greek`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=iso-8859-7.def&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any)?

Comment: #muru no. may i write sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-greek?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: #muru !!!!!It works perfectly!!!! You're my hero!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [quick search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=iso-8859-7.def&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) to see [which package provides](https://askubuntu.com/q/481/158442) `iso-8859-7.def` turns up `texlive-lang-greek`. Therefore installing it might solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-greek
```