# Installing the manual for getxattr

Tags: manpage

This is probably an easy one but I could not figure out. On my Fedora, I get the man page when I type `man getxattr`. However, on my **ubuntu 12.04**, I get `No manual entry for getxattr`.

Here are the packages I installed hoping I will get to see above man page:

```
# dpkg -l | egrep "manp|posix|glibc" | awk '{print $1" "$2}'
ii glibc-doc
ii manpages
ii manpages-dev
ii manpages-posix
ii manpages-posix-dev
```

Could you help me figure out which package I need to install to get this man page. BTW, There are quite a few other systemcalls/C-function/whatever man pages missing on my ubuntu. I chose `getxattr` for composing this post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `getxattr(2)` man page is from [the `libattr1-dev` package](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man2/getxattr.2.html). If you want it, install `libattr1-dev`. In general, if you can't find a manpage, look in http://manpages.ubuntu.com (which will show the package providing the manpage at the top), or use [`apt-file search`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/158442).