# Some system call man pages missing

Tags: manpage

On a 16.04 instance, I got the list of system calls using `man syscalls`. 
Most system calls have their own man page but a few do not:

```
$ man fremovexattr
No manual entry for fremovexattr
```

Ubuntu's website **does** have a manpage for that system call:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man2/lremovexattr.2.html

My question is what could possibly be the reason for not including the man pages for certain system calls?

Comment: The man page should be in /usr/share/man/man2/fremovexattr.2.gz  - if this exists then perhaps you need to update the man page index using 'sudo mandb'

Comment: That file does not exist so my question still stands but I did learn a new command. Thanks!

Comment: Its helps to me to use some basic `ls`, `grep` on man pages on its directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install libattr1-dev to get those specific man pages:

```
sudo apt-get install libattr1-dev
```

Comment: That doesn't directly answer the question but it did lead me down the right path. From `apt-cache show libattr1-dev`: _Description-en: 
 attr-dev contains the libraries and header files needed to develop
 programs which make use of extended attributes.  For Linux programs,
 the documented system call API is the recommended interface, but an
 SGI IRIX compatibility interface is also provided._
So I guess some system calls are not ready to be used _out of the box_, which explains why the man pages are missing.

Comment: I also found this similar post: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/714114/installing-the-manual-for-getxattr