# Where is file's source package?

Tags: 14.04, source-code, source

Where can I find the source for unix "file" command? Synaptic lists a "file" package but no file-src package. I'm not finding the source online either.

Comment: In combination with http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

Comment: I'm not sure but it's probably in the `coreutils` package. It's a group of GNU core utilities.