# How to disable auto display detection on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: xorg, gnome-shell, 19.10

I've found several issues similar since 18.04 it seems hard to disable and on 19.04 I've found a proper solution.
I have 3 displays 2 being active all the time the third one only being use every now and then.
For reasons unknown from time to time this screen turn on, when it does my 2 active displays blink change turn on off.
Is it possible to simply disable auto-configuration/hotpug of new display in Ubuntu and just do nothing and wait for user input to try to do anything to displays settings ?
Preious method such as the one here:
[How to disable monitor auto configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743473/how-to-disable-monitor-auto-configuration) seems to be ineffective in Ubuntu 19.10.
I've also try to install `dconf-editor` but the whole tool is useless as it seems there no key at all in it, both as a user and root.

Edit 1:

```
user$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active
false
```

Edit 2:

```
SESSION_MANAGER=local/kiwy-desktop:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1813,unix/kiwy-desktop:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1813
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
GDMSESSION=ubuntu
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Comment: What is returned when you type: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr active`

Comment: it returns `false`

Comment: can you update your question with results from `env | grep SESSION`

Comment: I'll check that tonight. Thank you for your help

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have added some information.