# Disabling display auto detection on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I am working on a system supporting multiple displays connected to an Nvidia display card (using DP).

Whenever I connect/disconnect a display all the remaining connected displays turn black for a couple of seconds until the displays are rearranged and then the image comes back.

**Is it possible to avoid this auto detection by the window/desktop manager?**
I want to avoid this short period of not showing an image on the monitors that were not changed.
The ideal solution for me would be to get notified when such a change in connected displays has happened but to do the configuration and placement myself.

I have tried to disable xrandr without any effect. Also tried to set the "UseHotplugEvents" to false in the xorg.conf without any effect.

This is similar to [How to disable auto display detection on Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188868/how-to-disable-auto-display-detection-on-ubuntu-19-10) but there is no answer there.

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully make it clearer

Comment: This is still an issue. My solution is never turn off the monitors. Yikes! I'm now on Linux Mint 21.3. Just default drivers installed.