# What package brings an application to the system

Tags: command-line, package-management

Some application may installed with a bunch of packages. For example, `vim` can go along with packages: `vim-gnome`, `vim-gtk`, `vim-nox` etc. To uninstall application I need to define what is the exaxt package actually installed me an application. How to define it? I would like to get it via command line.

---

The answer for my question slightly differs from answers to [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file):

```
$ dpkg -S "$(readlink -f `which vim`)"
```

Comment: Don't just look at the top or accepted answer of the linked question! The answer to your question is in [this answer](/a/1912/175814) and based on `apt-file`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Thank you. Actually for my purposes it less convenient than `dpkg -S` because `apt-file find vim` returns irrelevant result. There is a command `apt-file find `"$(basename $(readlink -f \`which vim\`))"` that returns two strings with `vim-nox` and `vim-nox-py2` and I need to choose one of them. And `dpkg -S "$(readlink -f \`which vim\`)"` returns `vim-nox` only

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-cache showpkg vim
```

This command with show both the `vim` packages dependencies and its reverse dependencies.

A package's dependencies are required for it to be installed; if you install a package, and of its dependencies that are not yet installed will be installed first (recursively:  if C depends on B, and B depends on A, the system will ensure that A is first installed, then B, and finally C).

A package's reverse dependencies are what you're asking of:  These are the packages for which the stated package *is* a dependency.  So, to use your example:

```
ghoti@home $ apt-cache showpkg vim
Package: vim
Versions:
2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language:
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages
                  MD5: 59e8b8f7757db8b53566d5d119872de8
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 59e8b8f7757db8b53566d5d119872de8


Reverse Depends:
  vimhelp-de,vim 2:7.5
  vimhelp-de,vim 2:7.4
  byobu,vim
  vim-vimoutliner,vim
  vim-tlib,vim
  vim-tabular,vim
  [and a whole bunch of others omitted for brevity]
Dependencies:
2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 - vim-common (5 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1) vim-runtime (5 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1) libacl1 (2 2.2.51-8) libc6 (2 2.15) libgpm2 (2 1.20.4) libselinux1 (2 1.32) libtinfo5 (2 6) ctags (0 (null)) vim-doc (0 (null)) vim-scripts (0 (null))
Provides:
[omitted for brevity]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use apt-file for this.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Then, you would use it like this

```
$ apt-file search `which vim`
```