# Corel Aftershot Pro 3 not starting in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit

The icon to start Corel Aftershot Pro 3 in Xenial Xerus doesn't start the Aftershot interface.

When you start the shellscript `/usr/bin/AfterShot3X64` from a terminal, you see `error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0`.

The full output is as follows.

```
Install Path:           /opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)
LD_PATH:                /opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)/lib:
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS:
./AfterShot: error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
gunang@waney-ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/AfterShot3X64
Install Path:           /opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)
LD_PATH:                /opt/AfterShot3(64-bit)/lib:
XLIB_SKIP_ARGB_VISUALS:
./AfterShot: error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

The Corel  application needs libgstreamer-0.10.so to start.

Install that library.

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-0
```

Comment: I've similar problem with Ubuntu 16.10.  This command doesn't work, cannot find package: "E: Unable to locate package libgstreamer0.10-0"

Comment: I was able to install the dependencies manually by downloading them from the Debian package search.  It's at https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.