# Ubuntu Docker Container update-ca-certificates: command not found

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dpkg

**This is running a Docker Container using the official Ubuntu 14.04**
The end result will be the same as [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates) once I can get that command installed.

New to Ubuntu and such, trying to get a docker container to update certs that i am linking in using `-v`.

Tried to use [dpkg -S update-ca-certificates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file) as described in the link and a few other answers that seemed to point in the same general direction. but i end up getting this in the container

```
root@24b087e56f8e:/# apt-get install -y ca-certificates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ca-certificates
```

2 Questions

1. How do you find out what package a command is installed with?
2. What package do I need to install with my container to get `update-ca-certificates` working?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

PEBKAC

turns out you need to run `apt-get update` before you can install any other packages. After running the updates you can then `apt-get install -y ca-certificates` and this is the package that contains the command `update-ca-certificates`

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu Docker Container run:

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get install ca-certificates -y`
3. `update-ca-certificates`

Comment: Seems like a reworded version of [workabyte's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/792432/816190)

Comment: apt-get install -y ca-certificates didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

try use: update-ca-trust, if u have installed ca-certificates but not work.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73620124/update-ca-certificates-command-not-found-despite-ca-certificates-being-installed

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1318866)