# Error when I am installing "caffe" when I do `make runtest`

Tags: make

I am installing caffe. I succeeded in running `make all` and `make test`, but when it comes to the `make runtest`, I receive the error:

```
.build_release/tools/caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [runtest] Error 127
```

What should I do about it? I am using [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/titipata/f0ef48ad2f0ebc07bcb9).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error seem to be pretty clear, you have to install cuda.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-dev
```

I wouldn't recommend to use CUDA, because 1) [CUDA is a crap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version/6622751#comment58383767_6622751), 2) You couldn't run ANN you made on most machines, except those with NVidia cards, for obvious reasons.

[You can compile without CUDA](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) by uncommenting in Makefile.config the line

```
CPU_ONLY := 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43828/discussion-on-answer-by-hi-angel-make-runtest-errorinstalling-caffe).