# File libsane.rules is completely missing

Tags: scanner

I try to make my Brother DCP7055 scanner working.
One of the steps is to add the Product/Vendor ID to libsane.rules.

This file is missing completely on my fresh Ubuntu-Studio 14.4 installation.
I have apt-get_installed all sane and lib-sane packages which came into my mind.

Thanks for advise
Frank

Comment: Where is that step you are talking about coming from? Add the instructions or tutorial you are following.

Comment: I think this isn't relevant at all.

I think the primary link came from here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=590793

After trying various troubleshooting sites I gave up and asked,

The file ''/etc/udev/rules.d/nn-libsane.rules`` defines the scanners known to sane. (Replace the nn by digits. This is used only to decide in which order the files in /etc/udev/rules.d/ will be processed and changes from distro to distro and time to time)

The problem is that THE FILE IS MISSING.

BTW:  I recognized that I am not on 14.4 anymore. The fresh install upgraded to 16.04.

Comment: Its not about what you think its relevant or whats not, its about what you can do to help us so we can help you.

Comment: Oddly: I'm here because I had and modified /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules , but it disappeared.  This is Ubuntu 16.04.  You can track what package made a file using https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS my scanner did not work. The upgrade deleted file 40-libsane.rules and replaced it with 60-libsane.rules without offering to keep/rename the old file. The new 60-libsane.rules did not contain my earlier edits to 40-libsane.rules. Redoing the old edits to the new 60-libsane file solved my scanner problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you please [edit] your question to explain exactly what you changed  (or provide us a copy of your current `libsane` rules) so that other people can solve their problem faster? Thanks!