# libRmath.so error

Tags: 16.04

I am running a software and it gives this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libRmath.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can you please help me fix this error, how to create this or install?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Search the contents of packages" on https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find the package that contains a given file.

For `libRmath.so` this finds [r-mathlib](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/r-mathlib). Installing that package will likely fix the error.

Comment: @star You should then accept this answer.