# Where to submit man page corrections?

Tags: manpage

In Ubuntu 17.04 I perceive that `man systemd-resolved` has a typo under the `OPTIONS -i INTERFACE` section referring to `/etc/systemd/resolve.conf` rather than `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`,  I.E. the difference is a `d`, and due to `/etc/resolv.conf` being so close yet different it is not beyond human oversight to typo the `man` page.

I find that the `man` page-referenced `/etc/systemd/resolve.conf` file does not exist. Who does `man` page corrections?

Comment: The maintainer of the package providing that manpage

Comment: report a bug against systemd .

Comment: That would be here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+filebug – however I could't find the typo you described in Zesty's [man systemd-resolved](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/systemd-resolved.8.html)…

Answer (score 5):

<sub>FWIW, I checked the man page myself, and I cannot find the error you mention! Perhaps it has been corrected? I am using Ubuntu (MATE) 17.04, regularly updated with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Have you tried updating your system?</sub>

---

Anyway, to answer your question in general terms:

#### `man` page errors are bugs

As mentioned in the comments, mistakes in `man` pages are bugs and should be reported to the package maintainers. See [the Ubuntu help wiki on bug reporting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

#### How to figure out which package provides a `man` page

Use `whereis` to find the `man` page file (as well as other main files), and `dpkg -S` to [find which package provides the file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file), for example

```
$ whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

The last file mentioned is the `man` page file - we can see that because it's in `/usr/share/man`, so we can find the providing package like this:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
coreutils: /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

So the package would be `coreutils`.

In your case:

```
$ whereis systemd-resolved
systemd-resolved: /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-resolved.8.gz
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-resolved.8.gz
systemd: /usr/share/man/man8/systemd-resolved.8.gz
```

So in this case the package to report a bug against is `systemd`

#### How to report the problem

First, [create a Launchpad account](https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount)

Since the problem is just a typo in the manpage, there is *probably* not much point in including all the usual debugging information that is included when you use Apport. Instead you could enter

```
http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/PACKAGENAME/+filebug?no-redirect
```

in the URL field of your browser, replacing PACKAGENAME with the name of the package.

You can then enter a short bug description, for example

```
typo in man page of `systemd-resolved`
```

You then get a form where you enter (as if there were still any doubt) which package you want to file a bug against, whether it is a security vulnerability (I'm pretty sure a typo in a man page won't be one...) and the details of the problem.

Don't forget to include which version of the package you are reporting against. You can check this with `apt policy <packagename>`

```
$ apt policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 232-21ubuntu5
```

Try to describe the problem as clearly as possible, imagining that you have to fix it yourself with no pre-existing idea of what's wrong. For example, you could give the subheading of the section where the error appears, copy and paste the text of the section with the mistake, explain why it is wrong and what it should say instead.

Comment: For the specific case of manpages, to locate the exact manpage that man shows, use `-w`: `man -w ls`, for example: `/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz`