# Where to report mistakes in a translated man page?

Tags: bug-reporting, manpage, adduser

I just discovered a mistake in the German version of the man page for `adduser`:

> **Einen System-Benutzer einrichten**
>   Wird **adduser** ohne  die Option **--system** und mit einem nicht optionalen Argument aufgerufen, richtet **adduser** einen System-Benutzer ein.

However, in the English version which I'm reading at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/adduser.8.html we have

> **Add a system user**
>   If called with one non-option argument and the **--system** option, **adduser** will add a system user.

The mistake is the word *ohne* (without), which should be replaced by *mit* (with). This actually confused me for quite some time, so I think it should really be corrected. But where can I report this "bug"? I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962659/where-to-submit-man-page-corrections) that man page errors are bugs, but the error is only in the translated version.

**Edit:** Thanks to muclux's answer I have filed a bug report against the project Ubuntu Translations:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+bug/1743251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs#translation) - there is a section on translation errors.

Comment: Thanks. I've reported the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-translations/+bug/1743251. Just to be sure: As target I choose the project *ubuntu-translations* and not the package *adduser* ?

Comment: Ah, never mind, they explain at the page you linked that all bugs should be filed against that project :-)