# Is there any possible way to recreate uname file in /bin?

Tags: filesystem

I've accidentally corrupted the `uname` file in the `/bin/` directory and now it does not return any information. Is there any possible way to recreate it?

Answer (score 32):

Locate the binary file:

```
$ which uname
/bin/uname
```

Find out [which package provides the file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file):

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/uname
coreutils: /bin/uname
```

Reinstall the package using the `--reinstall` flag

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

This replaces all the files of the package except configuration files.