# How can I search for a package which provides an uninstalled command?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I would like to search for which package provides an uninstalled command.

```
apt-cache search keyword
```

is good, but the search keyword can be all or part of a package name or any words used in its description, not necessary the name of a program/command.

Is there a better way?

For example, I can't tell which package contains the program `xlock`:

```
$ apt-cache search xlock
away - Terminal locking program
devrplay3 - rplay network audio system - basic library
librplay-perl - rplay network audio system - perl modules
librplay3 - rplay network audio system - shared libraries
librplay3-dev - rplay network audio system - development libraries
rplay-client - rplay network audio system - basic clients
rplay-contrib - rplay network audio system - contributed binaries
rplay-server - rplay network audio system - server
xautolock - Program launcher for idle X sessions
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not a duplicate: this asks about searching online while https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file is about searching on the system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install `apt-file`

```
sudo apt install apt-file
```

Perform an initial update of its database

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Then (for example)

```
$ apt-file search 'bin/xclock'
x11-apps: /usr/bin/xclock
```

See also [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/178692)

Comment: Thanks. In my example, `xlock` (**not** `xclock`) isn't installed, and I want to find out which package provides it.  Does `apt-file search` only search among installed programs?

Comment: @Tim no - AFAIK it searches all the (up to date) repositories in your currently configured APT sources

Comment: Thanks. wondering why use `apt-file search 'bin/xclock'` instead of `apt-file search xclock`?

Comment: I didn't find anything meaningful by `sudo apt-file search 'bin/xlock'` or `sudo apt-file search 'xlock'`.

Comment: @Tim I used `bin/xclock` simply to narrow down the search - if you don't get any hits with `bin/xlock` then try with just `xlock`, If you don't get anything meaningful then there is no package in your repositories that provides a file of that name.

Comment: xlock might be a complicated case - it used to be in the xlockmore package, which a lot of distros have (sadly) urged to phase out in recent years.

Comment: I had trouble finding what installs `dig` so I used `apt-file search -x '/dig$'` (or `apt-file search --regexp '/dig$'`). `man apt-file` says that `-x` is slow. You can also use `apt-file search dig | grep '/dig$'`. (It's also nice that you don't have to remember `-x` that way.)

Answer (score 4):

Normally on default installs of Ubuntu, when you type an uninstalled command in the terminal you should get a list of packages that provide it, or else a list of similarly-named commands if that specific command wasn't found; it seems that `xlock` is simply no longer provided in the main Ubuntu repositories. It was available for 12.04 (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xlock.1.html), but no longer.

For `xlock`:

```
$ xlock
No command 'xlock' found, did you mean:
 Command 'mlock' from package 'mlock' (universe)
 Command 'xclock' from package 'x11-apps' (main)
 Command 'vlock' from package 'vlock' (universe)
 Command 'lxlock' from package 'lxlock' (universe)
 Command 'wlock' from package 'sendfile' (universe)
 Command 'slock' from package 'suckless-tools' (universe)
 Command 'rlock' from package 'ruby-lockfile' (universe)
 Command 'flock' from package 'util-linux' (main)
 Command 'clock' from package 'xview-clients' (universe)
```

Example for one not installed but available:

```
$ rlock
The program 'rlock' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby-lockfile
```

Comment: +1 And also these outputs are made by  `command-not-found` package thats installed by default on Ubuntu. I guess its good to say the name of this package.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) and scroll down to "Search the contents of packages". Enter the program name in the box and click Search. A list of packages containing files named that will be displayed, without you having to install `apt-file`.

In this case, just like the other suggestions here, it will display nothing useful. That's because `xlock` came from the `xlockmore` package, `xlockmore` doesn't seem to have been shipped in Ubuntu since precise (released in 2012), and packages.ubuntu.com only has information for supported releases, currently back to trusty (released 2014).