# How can Clang static analyzer (scan-build) be installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, clang

In Ubuntu 16.04, I could:

```
$ sudo apt install clang
$ scan-build --help
USAGE: scan-build [options] <build command> [build options]
...
```

But in Ubuntu 18.04, after installing `clang`, the `scan-build` executable is not installed.

How can I use `apt` to install the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on a search at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/), it appears that `scan-build` has been split into a separate [clang-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/clang-tools) package.

More precisely, `clang` is a dependency package that, on 18.04, installs `clang-6.0`, while `clang-tools` depends on the corresponding `clang-tools-6.0` - which is the actual package that provides `scan-tools` for the current version of `clang`.