# Bash is not working fine on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: bash, lubuntu, qt

When I run the command `sudo bash` or `bash --version` I get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version 'Qt_5.10' not found (required by bash)
```

The output of `ldd` is as follows:

```
$ ldd `which bash`
/usr/bin/bash: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version Qt_5.10' not found (required by /usr/bin/bash)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc3e4e6000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f041be89000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f041bc85000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f041b43e000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f041acd5000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f041a949000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f041a1fe000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0419fdf000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0419c51000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f04198b3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f041969b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f04192aa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f041c0a6000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f041901e000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f0418dec000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f0418b4e000)
    libicui18n.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.60 (0x00007f04186ad000)
    libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f04182f6000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1 (0x00007f04180e5000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0417dcf000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f0417b9e000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f04178e8000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f0417634000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f0417407000)
    libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f041585e000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f04155ec000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f04152b3000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f041508b000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f0414e87000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f0414c81000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f0414a6c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f0414864000)
```

The output of `which bash` is:

```
/usr/bin/bash
```

Prior I tried to reinstall ruby as a bundle needed version 2.2.8 and i had ruby 2.5.RVM was not working fine so when i reinstalled ruby after that these error started occuring.

Comment: Which bash package is this? Does not look like the one from ubuntu at all

Comment: Please *always* add additional information directly to your question ([edit]) rather than in comments.

Comment: Bash depends on Qt library ? That doesn't sound right. Qt is GUI library, makes no sense.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy qt is also a networking library, but still it doesn't make sense :)

Comment: @SebastianStark  Well considering that bash can write to TCP/UDP sockets, networking makes sense to include, but  there's  default Unix API's for that.  Yeah, it still doesn't make sense :)

Comment: Have you tried to run `/bin/bash` explicitly? Does it behave the same way? You might also try to search [which package provides the file](https://askubuntu.com/q/481/250300) `/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: /bin/bash works fine

Answer (score 4):

Remove all your PPAs and/or third party packages and try again. This is not a standard Ubuntu package.

The normal bash command is in `/bin/bash`. You should be able to run it if you call it with the full path. The package in question, `/usr/bin/bash` is something you installed, perhaps by mistake, and it is taking precedence for the `which` command, because `/usr/bin` appears in `$PATH` before `/bin`.

You can circumvent the issue by changing your PATH variable such that it lists `/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I already did that bash is getting dependemt on QT.How to fix that?

Comment: see edited question.

Comment: How to fix that im totally confused?

Comment: You installed something on your system using instructions you do not understand. Try to revert this. Think hard what you did after installation. Try to find out which of these actions could have added `/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: It shows this error  bash: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.56: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory now can u help me fix this or can we manually change Path for Bash