# Where can I install unchanged (gnome-shell) ubuntu.css?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

I installed good theme, but before I changed /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css (This theme was bad). Now some changes are saved. I don't remember all change...

Help me!
Thank You!

Comment: You can boot from a live USB and get it from there.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file