# Accidentally removed libstdc++6, most programs not working

Tags: apt, package-management

Accidentally executed this command and now many of my programs are not working.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libstdc++6
```

`sudo apt` now not working and some other stuff.

How do I revert this?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

edit

I followed melebius by installing via dpkg -i ,libstdc++6 and it seems successful

```
root@server:~# sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++6:amd64.
(Reading database ... 71540 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
```

But when i tried to install something i get this error

```
root@server:~# sudo apt-get screen
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
root@server:~#
```

Comment: does firefox can work without `libstdc++6`? if it can, just download the package and reinstall it with `dpkg` (or get the package from another computer, transfer it with an USB driver)

Comment: i cant do any apt          root@:~# sudo apt-get update
sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: dpkg != apt, see the answer of @Melebius just bellow

Answer (score 1):

According to the packages web page, [`dpkg`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/dpkg) should be able to work without `libstdc++6` (unlike [`apt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/apt)).

So you should be able to download the correct version [`libstdc++6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libstdc++6) **for your architecture** manually and install it using `dpkg -i`, e.g.

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
```

In the case you cannot use your normal web browser on the machine in question, get the right URL elsewhere and download the file using `wget`, e.g.

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-5/libstdc++6_5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10_amd64.deb
```

---

According to the following error:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

you seem to have more missing required packages.

Check [which package provides the file](https://askubuntu.com/q/481/250300), download it and (re)install using `dpkg` like before. For `liblz4.so.1`, you need [`liblz4-1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/liblz4-1). Repeat this procedure with each file while APT complains about missing files.

---

One more thing… Your command invocation

```
root@server:~# sudo apt-get screen
```

indicates you are both logged in as `root` and using `sudo`. These two things are redundant, you need just one of them at a time.

Comment: ok..sorry for that melebius ,i'll fix the formating

Comment: i remember during executing the command (libstdc++6) ,there's confirmation dialog and i have to re enter confirmation word ..after that my perl,python script not working,apt get also not working. i dunno maybe during that confirmation, all the shared libraries also being removed ,even after i managed to install apt ,im end up with new problem (No sandbox user '_apt' on the system)..this is to much for new ubuntu user like my self ,so i end up asking server provider to reload my os ..but thanks melebius for your help

Answer (score 0):

I did the same mistake by deleting the libstdc++6, most programs were not working, `apt-get` as well. But I managed to restore the initial state by using.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```