# How do I find what package provides `javac`?

Tags: package-management, java

I'd like to find what package is installed on Ubuntu 14.04 (server) that gives access to the `javac` command.  The RHEL line of distros has `yum provides` for this, but there doesn't seem to be anything similar for the Debian family.

This [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file) suggests using `dpkg -S` and `apt-file`, but neither of these work:

```
$ sudo dpkg -S `which javac`
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/javac
```

`apt-file search` appears to work at first:

```
$ apt-file search javac
javacc: /usr/bin/javacc
```

Except that `apt-cache policy` shows that this package isn't even installed, so it's obviously not the package that provides `javac`.

```
$ apt-cache policy javacc
javacc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-5
```

How can I find out what package provides the `javac` command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, additional sleuthing is required. In particular,

```
$ ls -l $(which javac)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May 24  2017 /usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac
```

shows that `/usr/bin/javac` is a symbolic link - so we can either use `readlink` to drill down:

```
$ dpkg -S "$(readlink -f $(which javac))"
openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

or (seeing as it's an `update-alternatives` link)

```
$ update-alternatives --query javac
Name: javac
Link: /usr/bin/javac
Slaves:
 javac.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/javac.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Value: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac

Alternative: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Priority: 1081
Slaves:
 javac.1.gz /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javac.1.gz
```

from which we can pick out the current value:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

Comment: Very nice.  This was the issue.  `dpkg -S "$(readlink -f $(which javac))"` worked, and the package is `openjdk-7-jdk` (confirmed by `apt-cache policy`).  Thanks!

Comment: You should use `realpath` to simplify your process: `dpkg -S "$(realpath $(which javac))"`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `/usr/bin/javac` is a symlink managed by `update-alternatives`. What do you see if you `readlink -f /usr/bin/javac`? If it's pointing somewhere else, perhaps check *that* location with `dpkg -S`? Or `update-alternatives` itself can tell you which options you have for a particular link, eg:

```
$ update-alternatives --config javac
There is only one alternative in link group javac (providing /usr/bin/javac): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Nothing to configure.
```

So then:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
openjdk-8-jdk-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

All files in that package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openjdk-8-jdk-headless/filelist