# Is it possible to install libXft.so.2 on WSL?

Tags: package-management, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I wish to run a scientific GUI on WSL, which requires `libXft.so.2` package. Used `sudo apt-get` command, bash returned.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libXft.so.2
```

This is not about finding a file from package, it's installing a package, on WSL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: @Bhuvan Actually, this *is* because the single file is a file *included in* a package - find the package that provides the file and install that package, should "Just Work"

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it is not a package, rather it's a file—precisely file provided by some package.

[Looking up `libxFt.so.2` in packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libXft.so.2&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) yield `libxft2` package, so install it as follow.

```
sudo apt-get install libxft2
```

You can then check the file availability through `locate`.

```
:~$ locate libXft.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXft.so.2.3.2
```