# Accidentally deleted a dependency file. What do I do now?

Tags: dependencies, data-recovery, qt

I was recently debugging qt installed on the latest ubuntu and during by debugging efforts I accidentally deleted qt5widgets.so . Now, I have no idea to how to recover it as I already re installed qt, checked for broken dependencies with apt get and checked the trash bin which was empty. I don't know what to do now rather than getting a fresh OS and doing it all from the beginning.

Thanks in advance,
Cents

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @cmak.fr I already tried that but with no luck. Do you have any specific dependency I should try to use?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: s/accidentally/mistakenly/

Comment: @mook765 Version is 18.10

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is End of Life, thus not supported anymore. Please consider upgrading to a supported release.

Comment: What directory was qt5widgets.so in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out which package *thinks* it has `qt5widgets.so` with

```
dpkg -S qt5widgets.so
```

Then, force the reinstallation of that package with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename
```

Comment: It can't find any package with qt5widgets.so

Comment: look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt5widgets.so&searchon=contents