# Deleted mpicc.openmpi file by mistake

Tags: 18.04, mpi

In my infinite wisdom, I deleted the file 'mpicc.openmpi' file in my /usr/bin/ folder by mistake.

I tried installing OpenMPI as well as GCC. But don't know how to get back to normalcy.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file) In your case the package that provides the missing file is libopenmpi-dev (`sudo apt install libopenmpi-dev`).

Answer (score 0):

You can check which package provides the file like this:

```
dpkg -S mpicc.openmpi
```

which indicates it is in the `openmpi-bin` package. Then reinstall that package like this:

```
sudo apt reinstall openmpi-bin
```

After that, the file should be there again.

EDIT: forgot to add that this was for Ubuntu 19.04 -- the package name could be different for other Ubuntu versions.

Comment: The EDIT in the last paragraph explains the unexpected result that I got when I tried running the above command in Ubuntu 18.04. To be specific I have openmpi-bin installed in Ubuntu 18.04, but `dpkg -S mpicc.openmpi` does not say that it provides the missing file.