# After editing .bashrc, Ubuntu doesn't seem to be able to find some libraries/packages anymore. Any idea why?

Tags: apt, bashrc

Student coder here. I am trying to complete a project that asks me to install 
a package called "libncurses5-dev" and run a program through Ubuntu. 
It worked the first day, thankfully. However, on the second day I wanted 
to set my default directory to my homework folder so that I could skip the 
cd /mnt/c/Users/... step and just go straight to where my programs are. I 
tried to follow a tutorial online but I believe I made a typo or something 
because afterwards my Ubuntu kept crashing! I could not open it for long 
enough to fix it, the error was something along the lines of "directory does 
not exist." So, I uninstalled and reinstalled Ubuntu. I redid the process of 
installing all the packages I needed for coding on WSL. However, when I need 
to run my program, it keeps saying that I am missing a package. When I try 
to install that package, it says the package does not exist. Please see the 
attached files, which show what the project is supposed to look like and 
what it looks like now. I looked at image 2 again and it shows that I made
a typo in the library name, but after trying it again I get the same error 
anyways. Thanks in advance for the help.

[What it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAji5.png)
[What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu4VI.png)

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text, copy & paste the text into your question. A "Unable to locate package" message should tell you it didn't work, and as a student I'd expect you to realize binaries used by run-times aren't the same as -dev libraries used for compiles.. (unless that's part of what you're supposed to be learning in this step). You also install packages (which contain *shared objects*) not *shared objects* themselves...

Comment: The libncurses.so.5 runtime library is provided by package `libncurses5` - try reinstalling it

Comment: @steeldriver Hello, your solution worked. Quick and simple, thanks a lot. Is there some sort of documentation that I can use to tell me the different package names and their contents for future reference?

Comment: @FatinIftekhar please see [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: @Pilot6 yes it does, thank you