# How to install shared libraries

Tags: 20.04, shared-library

I have a problem with Cisco PacketTracer

https://www.netacad.com/courses/packet-tracer

```
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer7
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$
```

It turns out that some of the libraries are not there:

```
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ ldd PacketTracer7 | grep not
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 => not found
    libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Script.so.5 => not found
    libQt5ScriptTools.so.5 => not found
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$
```

I've tried to install it, but it didn't work:

```
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ sudo apt install libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5 libQt5Script.so.5 libQt5ScriptTools.so.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5
E: Unable to locate package libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5
E: Unable to locate package libQt5Script.so.5
E: Unable to locate package libQt5ScriptTools.so.5
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$
```

I've also tried to change it to lower case and remove `.so.5` from the name, but it still didn't work.

```
sudo apt install libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so libQt5WebEngineCore.so libQt5Script.so libQt5ScriptTools.so

sudo apt install libQt5WebEngineWidgets libQt5WebEngineCore libQt5Script libQt5ScriptTools

sudo apt install libqt5webenginewidgets libqt5webenginecore libqt5script libqt5scripttools
```

What is the right way to do this?

**Update**

This will install the first two libraries which are libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 & libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5, but not the last two:

```
sudo apt install libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webenginecore5
```

Two more libraries to be installed:

```
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ ldd ./PacketTracer7 | g not
    libQt5Script.so.5 => not found
    libQt5ScriptTools.so.5 => not found
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: @N0rbert, thanks but not at all ... I already know the path

`wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ dpkg -S PacketTracer7 
packettracer: /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library's name must be correct; it's case sensitive too. Try this:

```
sudo apt install libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

Also, use the shell script provided. Do not run the ELF file directly. That won't work.

```
/opt/pt/packettracer
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved libraries issue, but getting another error after that

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283343/packet-tracer-7-3-1-in-ubuntu-20-04-symbol-lookup-error

Comment: Check the answer here. 

https://askubuntu.com/a/1283474/1135027

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt install libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

It will pull a few more packages along.

I've used `apt-cache` to find those, for example, here are the first two

```
~$ apt-cache search libQt5Script
libqt5script5 - Qt 5 script module
libqt5scripttools5 - Qt 5 script tools module
```

...and the second two

```
~$ apt-cache search libQt5Script
libqt5script5 - Qt 5 script module
libqt5scripttools5 - Qt 5 script tools module
```

You can also combine two search words

```
apt-cache search 'libQt5WebEngine|libQt5Script'
```

Lastly, there is a searchable package database at https://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever. This install the first two. Another 2 libraries to be solved. I've updated my question with this info