# Packet Tracer 7.3.1 in Ubuntu 20.04 - symbol lookup error

Tags: software-installation

Initially, I had a problem with Cisco PacketTracer 7.3.1 [libraries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283326/how-to-install-shared-libraries) in Ubuntu 20.04.

Managed to fix it by installing the missing libraries.

```
sudo apt install libqt5webenginewidgets5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt5script5 libqt5scripttools5
```

However, I'm getting another error after that

```
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer7 
./PacketTracer7: symbol lookup error: ./PacketTracer7: undefined symbol: _ZN16QWebSocketServer19handleTCPConnectionEP10QTcpSocketRK7QString, version Qt_5
wolf@linux:/opt/pt/bin$
```

If you want to try, get it from [here](https://www.netacad.com/courses/packet-tracer). It's free, but registration is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't execute it directly. It won't work

```
/opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7
```

Instead, use the shell script in `/opt/pt/`

```
/opt/pt/packettracer
```

The path must be correct. Here is the snippet of that code

```
$ cat /opt/pt/packettracer 
#!/bin/bash

echo Starting Packet Tracer 7.3.1

PTDIR=/opt/pt
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pt/bin
pushd /opt/pt/bin > /dev/null
./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
popd > /dev/null
$
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround for your problem please try to execute packettracer as below:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pt/bin/ /opt/pt/bin/PacketTracer7
```

This worked on fedora 30 after I was getting same error, and I assume it will work for you too as it appears to be that all libraries needed are already installed in the same directory as PacketTracer7 binary.

Comment: `wolf@linux:~$ /opt/pt/PacketTracer7
bash: /opt/pt/PacketTracer7: No such file or directory
wolf@linux:~$`