# (Ubuntu 16.04) Where can I find gthread-2.0?

Tags: 16.04, source-packages

trying to compile qemu-stm32 I get this error message

```
ERROR: glib-2.12 gthread-2.0 is required to compile QEMU
```

but

```
sudo apt-get install gthread-2.0 (or just gthread)
```

resulted in

```
E: Unable to locate package gthread-2.0 / gthread
```

Any help will be appreciated.

M'

Comment: AFAIK it's part of [the libglib2.0-dev package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libglib2.0-dev/filelist)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file) Use packages.ubuntu.com to search for [.pc files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gthread-2.0.pc).

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. @steeldriver @ N0rbert