# Can someone explain why there exist two org.gnome.Software.desktop files? Which one (how) is loaded?

Tags: gnome, software-center, gnome-shell

Recently, I found that there are two `org.gnome.Software.desktop` files in two places:
one in

```
/usr/share/ubuntu/applications/
```

and one in

```
/usr/share/applications/
```

Can someone explain why (and how)

```
/usr/share/ubuntu/applications/org.gnome.Software.desktop
```

is loaded on the left rather than the latter?

Content of the file `/usr/share/ubuntu/applications/org.gnome.Software.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu Software
Comment=Add, remove or update software on this computer
# Translators: Do NOT translate or transliterate this text (this is an icon file name)!
Icon=ubuntusoftware
Exec=gnome-software %U
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;PackageManager;
# Translators: Search terms to find this application. Do NOT translate or localize the semicolons! The list MUST also end with a semicolon!
Keywords=Updates;Upgrade;Sources;Repositories;Preferences;Install;Uninstall;Program;Software;App;Store;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/appstream;x-scheme-handler/apt;x-scheme-handler/snap;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-software
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=gnome-software
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
DBusActivatable=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-software
```

Here is my desktop screenshot (Notice the left dock)
[image]

Here is my Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

I found that I can get the list of my apps from this command:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
['firefox.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop']
```

Therefore, I think my question can reduce to: **Is there an environment variable determining which `org.gnome.Software.desktop` is loaded**?

Comment: I found a similar question: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/gckepc/whats_the_difference_between_ubuntu_software_and/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: One is from the basic `gnome-software` package and the other from Ubuntu's custom version of that, `ubuntu-software`: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&mode=exactfilename&arch=any&suite=bionic&keywords=org.gnome.Software.desktop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: @muru Almost! Actually, I want to how `ubuntu-software` is loaded in the left side dock. Is there a file invoking it? Or is there a file that configure the dock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from this link https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/

> If multiple files have the same desktop file ID, the first one in the
> $XDG_DATA_DIRS precedence order is used.

if you run the command

```
echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

you will notice, `/usr/share/ubuntu/` before `/usr/share/`

Example:

```
$ echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
$
```

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the two files:

```
$ diff /usr/share/ubuntu/applications/org.gnome.Software.desktop /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Software.desktop
2c2
< Name=Ubuntu Software
---
> Name=Software
4c4
< Icon=ubuntusoftware
---
> Icon=org.gnome.Software
```

You see the `ubuntu` version uses "Ubuntu Software" and the generic version uses "Software".

Visually in your system you can see:

[image: ubuntu software.png]

Image Credit: [How to Install Gnome Software as Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 20.04](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/gnome-software-as-ubuntu-software-ubuntu-20-04/)

Click the link to find out how to change the setting.