# Which package do I have to install to get `gjslint` in Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: package-management, javascript

I've been using `gjslint` to verify that my JavaScript code is valid before sending it to my servers. Very practical.

In older versions (16.04, 18.04), it was found in the `closure-linter` package.

In newer versions (20.04), it was moved to the `closure-compiler` package (the `closure-linter` was removed/renamed).

In 21.04, it seems to be gone. I have `closure-compiler` installed and I can see `gjs` and `gjs-console`, but no `gjslint`.

Is there a way to use `gjs` as a linter only? Or is the linter hidden somewhere else?

Note: I ran [`apt-file find gjslint`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file) and it came up empty handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already found many parts of the puzzle.

Below are last bricks. Source package for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [mentions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/closure-linter) project page - https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/ .

It has the following:

> **Closure Linter is deprecated**
> [...]
> For teams using the Closure tools, we recommend they use the new linter based on the Closure Compiler instead. You can do this by passing `--jscomp_warning=lintChecks` to the compiler, or building the standalone linter binary; see the [Closure Compiler wiki](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Lint-checks) for details. The rest of the information on this page will be kept up for a while, for teams who are still using Closure Linter.