# How to get xcb/xcb_icccm.h

Tags: 21.04

I am trying to build bspwm, how do I get that dependency? I already have xcb installed. I'm on Ubuntu 21.04, the error message is

```
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -DJSMN_STRICT -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -DVERSION=\"0.9.10-33-ge22d0fa\"  -c -o bspwm.o src/bspwm.c
In file included from src/bspwm.c:39:
src/types.h:29:10: fatal error: xcb/xcb_icccm.h: No such file or directory
   29 | #include <xcb/xcb_icccm.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: bspwm.o] Error 1
```

Comment: [File list of package libxcb-icccm4-dev in hirsute of architecture amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/libxcb-icccm4-dev/filelist)

Comment: Thanks, what do I do with this information?

Comment: You install `libxcb-icccm4-dev`, since it is the package that contains the file

Comment: See also [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now it says I need xcb/randr.h. I did dpkg -S randr.h and installed x11proto-dev and  libxrandr-dev but it still says I need xcb/randr.h.

Comment: `dpkg -S` only searches packages that are already installed on your system - for files you don't have, you need to use the online package search or install and use `apt-file`. In this case, it looks like you need `libxcb-randr0-dev`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually I use the followying way to search a file in all entire repositories:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search xcb/xcb_icccm.h
libxcb-icccm4-dev: /usr/include/xcb/xcb_icccm.h
```

Or use [online search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xcb_icccm.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=hirsute&arch=any) at packages.ubuntu.com.