# Installation of mpicxx

Tags: command-line, mpi

I have mpich installed in my Ubuntu OS. But mpicxx in /usr/bin got deleted. It would be of great help if someone can help me re-install it.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: `sudo apt install mpich --reinstall`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: Yeah it worked thank you!