# Should I remove libraries from lintian and x86_64-linux-gnu directory?

Tags: 16.04, apt, libraries, shared-library, boost

I have some libraries namely related to `libboost`. I would like to remove it completely. But, even after doing `apt-get purge`, some files are still present in directories `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/` and `/usr/share/doc/`. Should I remove them, if so is there any procedure about how to remove these files?

I have the following files:

```
libboost_atomic.so.1.58.0
libboost-chrono1.58.0
libboost_chrono.so.1.58.0
libboost-context1.58.0
libboost_context.so.1.58.0
libboost-coroutine1.58.0
libboost_coroutine.so.1.58.0
libboost-date-time1.58.0
libboost_date_time.so.1.58.0
libboost-filesystem1.58.0
libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0
libboost-graph1.58.0
libboost-graph-parallel1.58.0
libboost_graph_parallel.so.1.58.0
libboost_graph.so.1.58.0
libboost-iostreams1.58.0
libboost_iostreams.so.1.58.0
libboost-locale1.58.0
libboost_locale.so.1.58.0
libboost-log1.58.0
libboost_log_setup.so.1.58.0
libboost_log.so.1.58.0
libboost-math1.58.0
libboost_math_c99f.so.1.58.0
libboost_math_c99l.so.1.58.0
libboost_math_c99.so.1.58.0
libboost_math_tr1f.so.1.58.0
libboost_math_tr1l.so.1.58.0
libboost_math_tr1.so.1.58.0
libboost-mpi1.58.0
libboost-mpi-python1.58.0
libboost_mpi_python-py27.so.1.58.0
libboost_mpi_python-py35.so.1.58.0
libboost_mpi.so.1.58.0
libboost_prg_exec_monitor.so.1.58.0
libboost-program-options1.58.0
libboost_program_options.so.1.58.0
libboost-python1.58.0
libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0
libboost_python-py35.so.1.58.0
libboost-random1.58.0
libboost_random.so.1.58.0
libboost-regex1.58.0
libboost_regex.so.1.58.0
libboost-serialization1.58.0
libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0
libboost-signals1.58.0
libboost_signals.so.1.58.0
libboost-system1.58.0
libboost_system.so.1.58.0
libboost-test1.58.0
libboost-thread1.58.0
libboost_thread.so.1.58.0
libboost-timer1.58.0
libboost_timer.so.1.58.0
libboost_unit_test_framework.so.1.58.0
libboost-wave1.58.0
libboost_wave.so.1.58.0
libboost_wserialization.so.1.58.0
```

Edit: This is not the same question as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file). In this question I am asking whether I can safely remove files/shared libs from `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. If so, how?
Clarification: `sudo apt-get purge libboost-date-time1.58.0` will also remove files like `libreoffice-calc*`, `libreoffice-core*`, `libreoffice-draw*`, `libreoffice-gnome*`, `libreoffice-gtk*`, `libreoffice-help-en-us*`, `libreoffice-impress*`, `libreoffice-math*` and some more files which seem important!

Comment: You should be careful with such removals. Deb packages depend on each other. Why do you need to remove these packages?

Comment: I want to install latest libboost libraries! The ones which I currently have here are of version 1.58.0!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Why you tag question with 16.04?

Comment: Yes my ubuntu version is 16.04!

Comment: Your Ubuntu version is EOL, so not supported on this site. You have to upgrade it latest 20.04 LTS version. Here you will get [boost 1.71](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libboost-all-dev).