# org.ayatana.bamf was not provided by any .service files

Tags: kubuntu, services

I get this error in the openrazer snake application splash screen as an unknown error.

I assume because it's given such prominence it's important but I can't find any information anywhere on how to setup this service.
There's no messages in any error logs regarding bamf.

Distro is kubuntu 22.04

Can someone point me to the documentation on setting this service up or just give me simple instructions for it please.

EDIT: I didn't add enough information here out of frustration.

I should have said I know which package provides the service, and that it is installed but the problem I had was that the service just wasn't starting.

Thanks to @muru I just needed to start the service as a user service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

Comment: `org.ayatana.bamf.service` is in [the `bamfdaemon` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=bamf.service)

Comment: I know which package is supposed to provide the service, and the daemon is installed but it is not providing the service the applications are looking for. So the question is how do I fix this missing service?

Comment: Is the bamfdaemon service running?

Comment: @muru The package is installed, the daemon does not appear to be running using a simple ps -ef scan, and there is no service called bamf or anything like it in the service --status-all output, nor does there appear to be a bamf command of any sort on the system.

Comment: @muru Also there is a bamfdaemon.service file in /usr/lib/systemd/user but any attempt to start it with systemd throws a service not found error.

Comment: Try `systemctl --user start bamfdaemon.service`

Comment: @muru That did it, can't believe I didn;t think of that, it's been too long since I had to mess about with services they usually just work without any intervention. tyvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.ayatana.bamf.service` in this case is a D-Bus service, defined in the `bamfdaemon` package and provided by the `bamfdaemon` service. The `bamfdaemon` service happens to be a user service, so to start it you'd need to do:

```
systemctl --user start bamfdaemon.service
```

You probably might want to enable it so that it's started automatically in the future:

```
systemctl --user enable bamfdaemon.service
```

---

AFAICT, the `bamfdaemon` package seems to have done everything correctly ([going by the docs](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html#session_services)) for D-Bus to automatically start the `bamfdaemon` service when the D-Bus service is needed. Both `/usr/lib/systemd/user/bamfdaemon.service` and `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.ayatana.bamf.service` look like the example in the documentation. I don't know why this isn't working correctly and why you had to manually start the service.

Comment: Not sure what's going on with it. I enabled it to autostart earlier and got a message back saying it is not meant to be enabled using systemctl because it is probably meant to be a support service for some other apps dependencies and/or it gets started when a app uses it but that just isn't what's happening, certainly not with the openrazer app. I'm going to accept your answer rather than mine as you have explained it so clearly to be of help to others that may come this way in the future.