# How to check which package/process updated nsswitch?

Tags: apt, ldap

I've experincing problems with my /etc/nsswitch.conf. I'm not longer able to use sudo as my personal user (ldap).

I've checked dpkg.log, and it seems it's been som upgrades on the packages which matches the date of the /etc/nsswitch.conf modification.

How can I further verify which package has edited the /etc/nsswitch.conf? I didn't get any useful results when I ran grep -rHi nsswitch /var/log.

I suspect sudo-ldap, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:** I've found this: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+question/706189. However, I'd like to know if it's possible to figure this out on the system itself!

Answer (score 5):

There are essentially two ways that a package can modify a file; either

1. the package contains a file that overwrites the original directly
2. one of the package's control files `preinst` or `postinst` modifies the existing file

If you have already installed the package, then you can check for (1) by looking at its file list e.g.

```
dpkg -L sudo-ldap | grep nsswitch
```

If you haven't already installed the package, you can check its contents online at
[packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) or using `apt-file` if you have installed that

```
apt-file list sudo-ldap | grep nsswitch
```

See also [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file)

---

For case (2), if you have already installed the package, you should find its control scripts in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` so for example

```
grep nsswitch /var/lib/dpkg/info/sudo-ldap.{pre,post}inst
```

or more generally

```
grep -l --include=\*.{pre,post}{inst,rm} '/etc/nsswitch.conf' /var/lib/dpkg/info/*
```

to list **all** the control files that mention the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file. If you want to examine the control files of an uninstalled package, you could do something like

```
apt download sudo-ldap

ar x sudo-ldap_*.deb

tar xvf control.tar.zst ./postinst
```

You can then view the file with a pager, or grep within it. In the case of the `sudo-ldap` package you will likely find the following

```
$ grep -A3 nsswitch ./postinst 
# modify nsswitch.conf if needed
if [ -z "`grep \"^sudoers:\" /etc/nsswitch.conf`" ]
then
        echo "sudoers:  files ldap" >> /etc/nsswitch.conf
fi

# make sure sudoers has the correct permissions and owner/group
```

Comment: I managed to find the following file as well and thank you for your answer, @steeldriver. However, it seems it was an upgrade of the package or something, but the result ended up being the `postrm` script being run, which didn't make sense to me since the package was/is still present on the system.